# How to use hwsim, "Module mac80211_hwsim not found in directory" error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wireless-networking, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have tried using this guide:
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/mac80211_hwsim

and did

```
modprobe mac80211_hwsim
```

However the output is:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module mac80211_hwsim not found in directory /lib/modules/...
```

How do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the kernel you are running isn't compliled with mac80211_hwsim.

You need to install another one, compile it with it, and install it.

If you have ubuntu you can use that guide:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

When it says "Modifying the configuration" add a CONFIG_MAC80211_HWSIM flag in the .conf or using make menuconfig

After you finish the installation reboot into the new kernel (choose it in grub), then you can modprobe mac80211_hwsim.

Comment: Can I avoid using another kernel?

Comment: you can compile the same kernel version you have, than insmod mac80211_hwsim manually from the compiled kernel folder.

Comment: I have moved to another pc in the meantime, after modprobing hwsim I can't seem to run hostapd the wlan0 it creates, it says it can't do "UP", I'm running as root, any idea why?

Comment: Maybe it is the network-manager, try sudo service network-manager stop

Comment: This is marked as solution, did it work?

Comment: Yes, it did, I have actually used the same kernel version, so I just insmoded the module after re-compiling the kernel with the flag (I was already running on my own compiled kernel), without having to reboot into another kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether  *mac80211_hwsim* code compiled or not watching to your config (according to `uname -r`) such way:

```
grep HWSIM /boot/config-*
```

If your kernel configured with `CONFIG_MAC80211_HWSIM=n` this code is not compiled and you can't use it without recompiling. If you have `CONFIG_MAC80211_HWSIM=m` it is compiled as module (seems it's not your case). Also it can be configured as `CONFIG_MAC80211_HWSIM=y` - this code is already built in your kernel, so you don't need to do `modprobe` or `insmod`.

Answer (score 0):

In latest Ubuntu I solved this by installing the package linux-modules-extra-{KERNEL_VERSION}-generic where this modules resides.